# codeigniter: why is codeigniter thinking the form is a get request instead of a post request

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

here is the form:

```
<?php echo form_open('locker_settingstwo/processform', array('class' => 'form-horizontal')); ?>
        <div class = "lockersettingstwodiv"> 
            <h2><?php echo $this->session->userdata('labelname'); ?></h2>
            <p> Control who can view/ReGemz the collection in this locker </p>
            <input type = "text" name = "testing" value = "" />
            <input type="radio" name="permission" value="1" /> Public - Others can view/edit this locker<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="permission" value="2" /> Me Only - Only you can view/edit this locker<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="permission" value="custom" /> Custom - Locked to everyone, meaning only friends I choose can view/edit this locker<br/>
        </div>
            <input type="submit" name = "Next" value="Next" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 14px" />
            <input type="submit" name = "Cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 14px" />
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

now when I'm printing the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], its saying GET, instead of POST...why is that?

here is the controller method that the form is sending to:

```
function processform() 
{
    echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
}
```

Comment: When are you printing the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ?

Comment: What does $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') return?

Comment: form_open uses POST method by default so it can't be unless you're doing the server request method somewhere else. If its actually GET you wont get anything once you print_r($_POST) on the file that's processing the form.

Comment: i always accept, i don't know y its not higher..

Comment: @dave, accept an answer on your famous question and you may get more biters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your host set up? There are times when you are using a FastCGI SAPI that the POST attributes are translated to the `$_GET` superglobal as a result of the redirect/forwarding.

What SAPI are you using?

Comment: SAPI = Server API. Use this: `echo php_sapi_name();` or `echo PHP_SAPI;`

Comment: outputs cgi-fcgi for echo php_sapi_name()

Comment: so what does cgi-fcgi mean exactly?

Comment: You can read up on `FastCGI` here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI. It's always a great read. In short though, this is how the webserver passes information received to PHP. Sometimes, depending on what SAPI you are using, you need to access data in a different way. Somethings to try to see if your data is making it to the script is, running `var_dump( get_defined_vars() );` which will display all defined variables in PHP.